# Problems to upload photos in Object detection google API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-vision

I'm trying to upload photos to train my model for object detection API, but I couldn't click on the Import button even I uploaded the photos, in Image classification it works but here, I couldn't, someone knows the answer, please? I tried as well to upload the CSV file from my bucket, but I got so many errors !

> line 13: Expected 11 columns, but found 2 columns only

Comment: What does your csv file look like around lines 12-14?

Comment: This is what I have between the lines 10 and 14 in the CSV file, only the link of photos: 
UNASSIGNED,gs://first-edge-253208-vcm/uploads/new-dataset/20191011143425728/Sombrillita (10).jpg
UNASSIGNED,gs://first-edge-253208-vcm/uploads/new-dataset/20191011143425728/Sombrillita (11).jpg
UNASSIGNED,gs://first-edge-253208-vcm/uploads/new-dataset/20191011143425728/Sombrillita (12).jpg
UNASSIGNED,gs://first-edge-253208-vcm/uploads/new-dataset/20191011143425728/Sombrillita (13).jpg
UNASSIGNED,gs://first-edge-253208-vcm/uploads/new-dataset/20191011143425728/Sombrillita (14).jpg

Comment: Furthermore, I still can not use the option of upload the photos from my Computer? I don't know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSV file isn't formatted correctly (Missing 9 out of the 11 necessary columns). You are missing the identification label as well as the bounding box coordinates for an object within the image.

Please refer to [this](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/object-detection/docs/csv-format#csv) documentation as it provides the correct CSV formatting guidelines for AutoML Vision Object Detection.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  So far, I really don't know how to upload my own photos using this method, I have already uploaded my photos using the ui interface in the image classification, but the object detection interface doesn't accept uploading my photos locally or from my backet.

Is there an example in youtube that explains that? because in the link you sent me, it is not clear how to do it for all rows and colomun

Comment: I tried to use again the link that uou have sent to me, I added some colomns in my CSV file, but I still receiving again some errors of not finding a file even it exists in my bucket ... Error: Cannot find the specified file: gs://first-edge-253208-vcm/uploads/new-dataset/20191011142812156/cualerpa4.jpg.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce the error that you are receiving.

If you are still experiencing this issue, try the "Upload Images from your computer" within import.

Another option would be to upload a single image using "Upload images from your computer" then export the data (it exports a csv). Afterwards go to your GCS bucket where the exported csv was saved, download it and modify it to incorporate other images located within the same bucket.

Comment: Now, it is working, when I tried in the past to upload the image, I didn't specify the destination folder in my bucket, so I couldn't click on the Import button, now I can the uploaded images form my computer, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had 4 columns instead of 12, so I think mainly these are **borders**, however, 
**please check the whole sequence**, cuz I eventually found out that I link buckets incorrectly.

`gs://folder/video.mp4,name,(one empty space),20.50(timestamp),0.8,0.8,0.9,0.8,0.9,0.9,0.8,0.9(object detection "square" borders)`

`inf` timestamp was working with label detection, but not with object, but with correct timestamp and empty one is proceeding. Again, one line of code is looking like that:

`gs://folder/video.mp4,name, ,20.50,0.8,0.8,0.9,0.8,0.9,0.9,0.8,0.9`